# cmath syntax errors when building a C wrapper for a C++ library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

Now I am developing a C++ library, which is expect to have C interface. In order to do that I have two solutions:

Solution 1:

```
lib_c_header.h
lib_c_header_imp.cpp
```

Solution 2:

```
lib_c_header.h
  lib_c_header_imp.c
```

Then the first question I have is : is it valid to have a C interface header and C++ implementation file as a wrapper of the C++ library?

Then move to the second solution, I will create a C interface header and C implementation file. In the C implementation file, C++ classes from the library will be invoked. However, when I do that, I always have cmath syntax errors:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'
```

These errors lead me to the following codes in the `cmath` file:

```
_STD_BEGIN
using _CSTD acosf; using _CSTD asinf;
using _CSTD atanf; using _CSTD atan2f; using _CSTD ceilf;
using _CSTD cosf; using _CSTD coshf; using _CSTD expf;
using _CSTD fabsf; using _CSTD floorf; using _CSTD fmodf;
using _CSTD frexpf; using _CSTD ldexpf; using _CSTD logf;
using _CSTD log10f; using _CSTD modff; using _CSTD powf;
using _CSTD sinf; using _CSTD sinhf; using _CSTD sqrtf;
using _CSTD tanf; using _CSTD tanhf;
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that the implementation file `lib_c_header_imp.c` will be compiled as C file while in the file some C++ classes will be invoked.  I was wondering whether there is a solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: "Now I am developing a C++ library, which is expect to have C interface" - that should really be the other way around. People don't write assembly wrappers for JavaScript libraries.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, inaccurate presentation.

Comment: @H2CO3: That's definitely _not_ the wrong way around. C is the least common denominator and usually the only one that can be reasonably bound to anything. So it happens whenever you need to bind something in language A to language B, you need to do the glue in C. There are many C++ libraries that have pure C interface for this reason.

Comment: @H2CO3 Currently I am developing a C++ library which is used by a large Fortran program. In order to allow Fortran90 code to call my C++ code I had to provide a C API - C functions can be called easily from Fortran. This is a real life, serious, project.

Comment: Are you including `<cmath>` in `lib_c_header_imp.c`?

Comment: @DyP yes, but when I remove <cmath> and use <math.h>. The error still happens.

Comment: @JanHudec You didn't get my point. If a library is written in C, of course it has its primary API exported as C. It's only that one can write a C++ wrapper for that. And that's how it should be done.

Comment: @H2CO3: We are not talking about library written in C. We are talking about library written in C++ (because writing it in plain C would be just silly; developing in C++ is faster and the result is often faster as well) that needs to provide a C interface. That's how life is. If you want to call it from any other language than C++ (Fortran in this case), you need a C interface.

Comment: @JanHudec Okay, I understand what you mean. (Although, on a side note, I don't agree with the "writing it in plain C would be just silly" part.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to write a C function that calls C++ is to compile it in C++ in an `extern "C"` block. Because the body of the function still has to be C++. So you'll have to have `lib_c_header_imp.cpp`.

You may either have separate header for the C wrapper and the full C++ interface or you may have them together in one header with the C++ part guarded by `#ifdef __cplusplus`. Depends on how big it is and how it will be most often used etc.

In the header you may only include C headers (i.e. `<math.h>` rather than `<cmath>`) or you may include C++ headers under `#ifdef __cplusplus`, but than you  obviously can't use their content in the C wrapper part.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can include C in C++, i.e. use a C++ compiler when compiling the source. However, you can not use a C compiler to compile C++ code.